# Sending Velocity templated Emails with images in them from a Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, email, velocity

I'm interested which is the best way to send Emails with images in them from a Spring MVC application which uses Velocity.

The image should be in the application, possibly in the same location as the `*.vm` template (e.g. `src/main/resources/templates`) and no absolute paths should be used (e.g. C:\App...), that's why I can't figure it out how to do it.

Suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I suppose that you've solved your problem. Why don't you accept your favourite answer? Wasn't it helpful?

Comment: I solved it on a third way :) I added links to the images in the template with with `final Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();` and then `model.put("urlLogo", urlLogo);` and then `VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine,
                "emailTemplates/template.vm",
                model);`

Comment: Great, you could add your solution as a new answer and then accept it.

Comment: I'll do that, additionally to note that the solution was from Spring in Action book, in chapter 14: "Odds and ends" title: "Sending email".

Comment: hi Martin Spa, can you provide source code how to solve it? Now I am facing problem. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand how images and emails work together. I'm not an expert here, but I think the options are

- include the image as an attachment in the email (lame, IMHO; and your bandwidth usage will be very high)
- send an HTML email and link to an image hosted on the Internet

Have a look at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper

Answer (score 2):

With Spring you can easily load resources from file system or from classpath (even within jar file) without absolute paths. You should use a `Resource` and its implementations, basically `FileSystemResource` or `ClasspathResource`.
This is an example:

```
Resource fileResource = new FileSystemResource("resources/templates");
```

After loading you can directly retrieve inputstream from resource instance.

Also, you can inject your relative path to a bean which has an instance attribute of type Resource:

```
<bean id="mailer" class="test.Mailer">
    <property name="templateResource" value="file:resource/templates" />
</bean>
```

I don't use Velocity but I usually load templates in this way to generate dynamic content with freemarker. You can also attach an image to an email, once you've loaded it.